# El Modal de Bootstrap no se visualiza

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, modal

Hola tengo un problema con el modal de bootstrap solo puedo usar css y html en esta ocasión por lo que es raro que me falle ya que no encuentro motivos, he revisado varias preguntas similares de compañeros por esta via pero no he encontrado el error en el mio por eso subo mi pregunta. Se supone que al hacer click en el boton "New Post" abriria un Modal.

```css
//*dejo por aca el Css a ver si creen que algo del Css este afectando el funcionamiento del modal*//

body{
    background: rgb(155, 153, 153, 8);
}
.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light.bg-light{
    width: 90%;
}
.header-navbar{
    width: 999px;
    margin: auto;
}
div.container{
    margin-left: 6%;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}
.post{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;       
}
.Top{
    display: block;
}
.Top h3{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: rgb(155, 153, 153, 8)
}
.Top h2{
    float:left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.post .img img{
    width:100%;
}
.post .footer{
    padding: 20px;
}
.button {
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -6%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theInstagramPhotoFeed.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    
    <header>
        <div class="header-navbar">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
       <!--aca empieza el form del modal-->
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
<!--boton que contiene el modal--><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mi-modal" >New Post</button>
                        
      <!--aca empieza el modal-->                  
                        <div class="modal" id="mi-modal">
                              
                            <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                  </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                  <input id="text" style="width: -webkit-fill-available; height: 50px; border-radius:5px;"></input>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
</div>
</form>
                <dl class="navbar-nav mr-auto2"></ul>
                    <dt class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                        </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                    </dt>
                </dl>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="button">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" >
        <i class="fas fa-grip-horizontal"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-stop"></i>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-left: 17%;">

    <div class="post">
        <div class="Top">
            <h2>Some cute thing</h2>
            <h3>10/03</h3>
            <div class="img">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <p>This is my firts photo of the feed. This is a multy line comment for testing purpose. I am
                    learning to code with #breathecode</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    <footer></footer>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

. Gracias por su atención de antemano.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como se ve en la imagen solo se opaca la pantalla pero no ejecuta el modal. Estoy usando internet para el bootstrap por lo que no creo que sea problema de compatibilidad de versiones. Revise temas ya como la apertura y cierre de etiquetas copie y pegue el codigo original otra vez y me sigue saliendo asi aunque en una oportunidad si me funciono. No se que pueda ser ya porfa agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: ¿ Porque tienes 2 divs con la clase modal ?, puede que este sea el problema

Comment: No amigo Joel, también intente eso ya, añadiendo un carácter a la clase de uno de esos div y seguía igual con la falla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He quitado la clase modal a uno de los `div` y funciona quizá había conflicto de clases y por eso no te funcionaba.

```css
//*dejo por aca el Css a ver si creen que algo del Css este afectando el funcionamiento del modal*//

body{
    background: rgb(155, 153, 153, 8);
}
.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light.bg-light{
    width: 90%;
}
.header-navbar{
    width: 999px;
    margin: auto;
}
div.container{
    margin-left: 6%;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}
.post{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;       
}
.Top{
    display: block;
}
.Top h3{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: rgb(155, 153, 153, 8)
}
.Top h2{
    float:left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.post .img img{
    width:100%;
}
.post .footer{
    padding: 20px;
}
.button {
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -6%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theInstagramPhotoFeed.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    
    <header>
      <div class="header-navbar">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <!--aca empieza el form del modal-->
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <!--boton que contiene el modal--><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mi-modal">New Post</button>

              <!--aca empieza el modal-->
              <div class="modal" id="mi-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">

                <div>
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <input id="text" style="width: -webkit-fill-available; height: 50px; border-radius:5px;">
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <dl class="navbar-nav mr-auto2">
              <dt class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </dt>
            </dl>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="button">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-grip-horizontal"></i>
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-stop"></i>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-left: 17%;">

      <div class="post">
        <div class="Top">
          <h2>Some cute thing</h2>
          <h3>10/03</h3>
          <div class="img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400">
          </div>
          <div class="footer">
            <p>This is my firts photo of the feed. This is a multy line comment for testing purpose. I am
              learning to code with #breathecode</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <footer></footer>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ya le dije en el comentario :)

Comment: si ejecutas el script si que funciona.

Comment: Gracias amigo ahí si ejecuta el Modal.. al final me funciono hace días pero volví a escribir el código de otra manera. igual excelente resolución bro te agradezco. Buen aporte.